# How to lazy load an image for a small screen but not a wide screen?

Tags: html, css, lazy-loading

I use the native `loading=lazy` parameter in the image tag to lazy load images which are for most users off-screen. However, what is off-screen depends on the browser window size. For example, on a typical mobile device three images are visible on one of my webpages, but on a typical desktop 8 images are showing. Since server-side I cannot know the size of the user window/screen how can one conditionally lazy load an image based on window size?

I have tried to put two copies of the image into the HTML, one with the `loading=lazy` parameter and one without and then with a CSS media query to show one or the other with `display:none`. This does not work. Browsers load the image regardless of if the image element is displayed or not. Hiding the regularly loaded image does not prevent it from being loaded.

Comment: have you tried using ```<picture>``` tag?: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/picture

Comment: The `<picture>` tag is not a solution for lazy loading. It allows one to specify an alternative image file for different screen sizes, for example, but does NOT allow one to have `loading=lazy` on one source and `loading=eager` on another source in the same tag. At least that is my understanding. If I am wrong please provide an example of how this can be done.